# Django redirect back to admin login page using reverse() not working

Tags: python, django

I'm new to `Django version 2.1`, In Middleware where if `user_logged` session is empty i'm redirecting it to `admin` url

I'm getting `NoReverseMatch at /demo/list
Reverse for '../admin/' not found. '../admin/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.` error.

project urls.py

```
    from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('demo/', include('demo.urls')),
]
```

setting.py

```
    MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'demosite.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleWare',
]
```

project middleware.py

```
    import re
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse

class LoginRequiredMiddleWare:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)

        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        print(request.session.get('user_logged', None));

        if not request.session.get('user_logged', None):
            return redirect(reverse('admin/'))
```

app urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path, include
from demo import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('list', views.demoView.listData, name='list-data')
]
```

FOR REFERENCE BELOW IS SCREEN SHOT OF PROJECT DIRECTORY STRUCTURE
[image: SCREEN SHOT OF PROJECT DIRECTORY STRUCTURE]

### THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: You don’t need to call reverse() there. redirect() is enough.

Comment: @art06 I have called `redirect('admin/')` but this appends to app url like this `localhost/demo/admin/` I want like this `localhost/admin/`

Comment: The redirect string should be absolute path /admin/

Answer (score 3):

In order to use `redirect` or `reverse`, you should use the route `name`.  In admin.site.urls, the routes are:

```
        urlpatterns = [
            path('', wrap(self.index), name='index'),
            path('login/', self.login, name='login'),
            path('logout/', wrap(self.logout), name='logout'),
            path('password_change/', wrap(self.password_change, cacheable=True), name='password_change'),
            path(
                'password_change/done/',
                wrap(self.password_change_done, cacheable=True),
                name='password_change_done',
            ),
            path('jsi18n/', wrap(self.i18n_javascript, cacheable=True), name='jsi18n'),
            path(
                'r///',
                wrap(contenttype_views.shortcut),
                name='view_on_site',
            ),
        ]
```

so you would want to redirect as follows:

```
return redirect('admin:index')
```

For the login page, you would use:

```
return redirect('admin:login')
```